# Angular2 typescript how to get object properties to display in template

Tags: typescript, angular

I am learning angular2 and typescript and wondering why I can not access property values of the object in my template.

**My component:**

```
export class Farm{

    data:JSON;
    id: any;

    constructor(private nextService: NextService, navParams: NavParams){
        this.id = navParams.get("param1");

    }

    getFarmDetails(){

        this.data = this.nextService.fetchData(this.id)
        console.log(this.data)
    }
}
```

where console.log(this.data) gives me `Object {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: Object…}`

In my template I have

```
<div>
    {{data}}
</div>
```

which outputs on my screen as [object Object]

How can I instead output properties like email or username?

UPDATE: If I do like {{data.email}} I get following error:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can access those properties as you would in javascript.

For example:

```
{{data.email}}
```

If the data is retrieved asynchronously you can use the elvis operator **?.** to avoid the errors while data is null.

```
{{data?.email}}
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me another hour of debugging issues and facepalming. The "elvis" operator is also called the "safe navigation operator" sometimes

Comment: @SoFLy that's what SO is for. :)